# How to calculate the covariance-standardized residuals from a joint distribution estimated with the copula density function

Tags: residuals, copula

I have issues when reading a paper when calculating the eta parameter in the following equation
[image]

where the authors of the paper describe eta as the vector of the covariance-standardized residuals, which can be simulated from a joint distribution estimated with the copula density function. Can someone help me by explaining what they mean and how they are calculating this variable?

I'll leave the full link to the paper here: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377221721005300